# Average takeoff distances of a variety of aircraft

Tags: statistics

[image: average takeoff distances (in feet) of a variety of aircraft]

I'm honestly really confused about how to approach this problem. I notice there is a huge gap between the numbers considering one take off distance is as low as 400 and another is as large as 1495 but I don't really know what I can deduce from this data?

Answer (score 2):

When you are exploring data, a plot is often useful.  I would make a histogram of the numbers.  Since you did not plot the numbers in a way they can be easily copied, I have not done so.  Just looking, you might find the data clumps into a few areas.  That might lead you to theorize that the airplanes can be grouped into classes, perhaps small, medium, and large, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume some of the different takes offs take longer to get up to the speed required to take off. I assume the heavier the aircraft (passengers, cargo etc) the longer it takes to take off due to the weight. Also there could be different pilots, some being better than others.